# SVN server specs

Tags: svn, hardware

Here at work, a small Flash game developer, I've been tasked with setting up an SVN server. I need to advice the boss on what machine he should buy.

The server will run SVN, Trac and MediaWiki and the repository will contain fairly large binary files. We are with 10 people, and the server will be accessed over LAN.

The specs that I have in mind are:

- Large hard disks in software RAID1
- Moderate RAM, 2 GB or so
- Moderate CPU, like single core 2,6 GHz

Does that sound right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subversion` itself is pretty light.  Trac and MediaWiki are pretty light as well.  So your hardware should be fine (I run `subversion` on a tiny linux VM with 256mb ram and it runs fine).

Basically, for your use case (with only 10 users) any server should be fine.  The more RAM the better (Since MySQL can perform better with it), but it's not absolutely necessary.  If you ever decide to make the server public, then you have a different issue...

The other scenario where the "beefiness" of the server matters would be if you're using it as a build server (where you're running something like `CruiseControl` or `Hudson` as a continuous integration platform.  Then the speed will matter since you're actually going to be doing something on the server other than simple tasks...

Answer (score 1):

More RAM won't hurt, and you can make sure the network card is gigabit ethernet. Otherwise, I'm sure it'll be fine. You'll want fast I/O, so network and drive speed is important.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why more RAM is necessary, so I can justify it?

Comment: More RAM means you can have more files open at the same time. Plus it's cheap now.

Answer (score 1):

Dual-Core Machines are standard today, so I'd go with that; Something in the 2GHz range is fine.

Your memory is adequate, but more is of course better.

I'd actually go with many disks (4 minimum) at RAID6.  There is a minimum of 4 disks to a RAID6 array, but two disks can fail and still be up and running.  I'm also a fan of RAID10 (sometimes written 1+0), but that trades a little more speed for a loss in flexibility.

-Waldo

Comment: ...and a loss in reliability with RAID 10, where if you have the wrong two disks fail, you're screwed. With RAID 6, any two disks can fail without data loss.

Comment: I think that "flexibility" describes the loss potential better than "loss of reliability", but for the same reasons.  I agree with you in principle, but not in description.